# How do you delete shared drives from google drive

Tags: google-drive

I recently worked with a file from a link, now it is indexed in my "Shared with me" folder and is taking up space in my drive folder. It lists itself as a shared drive [image]

but I can't delete it
[image] and if I try to remove my self from the user permissions I can't

[image]

So it's stuck in my Google drive "Shared with me" section, taking up storage space on my drive, I don't have permission to remove myself, and I can't get into contact with the owner to have them delete me from the permitted users list.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item isn't taking up storage space, as the storage quota comes off the organization that owns the Shared Drive. It is however displayed in Shared with Me, and that is your concern. So, it is more a problem of organization/clutter. Under usual circumstances, one would be able to remove the item from Shared with Me, but that option is disabled. I confirm that I'm able to reproduce the problem.

The best way forward is to leave feedback to the Google Drive developers about how you don't like this problem. You can do that by clicking on the ? icon on the top right of [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com/), then clicking "Send feedback". Alternatively, in the mobile app, tap the menu, then tap "Help and feedback", then "Send feedback".

Comment: That is sad that google doesn't even have a fix to this problem, but oh well.

How confident are you that it's not taking up any space on my Gdrive? I only have 1 15mb file in my Gdrive, yet after this being put in my "Shared with me section"I now have 12GB used up by Gdrive which could only be coming from the "shared with me" section.

Comment: Go to the info for the item — it will say there who the owner is. Items in a Shared Drive are owned by the organization which manages the Shared Drive. Items only take storage space from the owner of the item.

Comment: It says it's using 0 bytes of storage in my drive, but my storage was at 1% full before, and now it's at 12GB of used space, could it be a bug?

Comment: On the left where it says "12GB of 15GB used", please click on that. It will take you to https://drive.google.com/drive/quota , where you can see which items are taking up the most storage in your Drive storage.

Comment: As I've said, my storage quota is not coming from Gdrive, these are the only things on it, and they don't add up to 12GB. https://imgur.com/a/irBu78s

Comment: Go to [account.google.com](https://account.google.com/), then click on "Manage storage". It will show you how much storage each app is taking up. It could be Gmail or Google Photos which is using up your storage space.

Comment: The image I showed you earlier is all I have in my drive, yet... https://imgur.com/a/w64tXX8

Comment: Please try looking at your orphaned files. Search [`is:unorganized`](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=is:unorganized) to view items that are not stored in any folder in your Drive. There may be items there that you want to be stored in a folder, or to be deleted.

Comment: That's only another 32MB worth of files https://imgur.com/a/7qTkbd8

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you further. If you upgrade your storage plan, you will have access to the Google Drive help desk, so I would then recommend asking them for support.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to drag and drop to the trash bin on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Delete first all the elements in the drive.
than you will be able to delete the drive(if you have "manager" permissions)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).